# How to profile Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-odm

How can I profile Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

I would like to see all queries against database and the time of execution. Is there any way to configure a profiler? I would like to build a plugin that I would use it in ZFDebug toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

The [MongoDBODMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule/tree/0.7.0/src/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Logging) for ZF2 may have some classes you could re-use to handle this problem in ZF1. If you're already using ZF2, then it is just a matter of installing the module and [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) to have the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has its own profiler, check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/